# on Mouse-Hover Image Focused / Grid gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery, onmouseover, fancybox-2

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Doodle/d3sLj/5/embedded/result/)
[image: screenshot]

The Need of the concept is...
 
There are thumbnails.
The thumbnails remains covered with a black overlay). 
**on Mouse-hover on a certain image, it gets lighted up** ( or an animation of flip or rotation would be a bonus...lol) 
On Clicked, the image is brought up to its real dimensions through fancybox.
I have tweaked around with the fancy box script & the fancy box function is already happening.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding : 0,
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    openSpeed: 250,

   closeEffect: 'elastic',
   closeSpeed: 450,
   closeClick: false,

    helpers : {
    overlay : {
        css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)'
        }
    }
}

});
```

[Working code](http://jsfiddle.net/GsRxs/)
I need some help to modify on the existing code for the on-hover function (or the animation) (^_^) 
Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick sample of how to get animation on hover :

```
$(".fancybox").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find("img").stop(true, true).animate({
        "opacity": 0.1
    }, "slow");

}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find("img").stop(true, true).animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }, "slow");

}).fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    openSpeed: 250,

    closeEffect: 'elastic',
    closeSpeed: 450,
    closeClick: false,

    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)'
            }
        }
    }

});​
```

Your working code **[UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/GsRxs/1/)**

That is the basic structure you need to create the effect wanted.

```
... or an animation of flip or rotation would be a bonus
```

... are you talking about a $$$ bonus ?  ;)

Comment: Hi @JFK , thank you for the update :).your code update did the trick.However, i was looking for the opposite action as in the image remains with low opacity on load, mouse enter, it comes to 100 opacity :). Update here: http://jsfiddle.net/GsRxs/2/ . Is there a lesser 'lines of code' way to do that gain?. By Bonus, I meant the extra help would be a bonus to me..hehe